# How to set text right after textbox twitter bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form elements using the following markup.. And the current look of the form you can find in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I set the "In" and"Lbs" right after their corresponding textbox?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 control-label">Height:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />In
    </div>
    <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">Weight:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
    </div>
    <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">BMI:</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />Lbs
    </div>
    <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">Waist:</label>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Bootstrap's [input groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#input-groups) to attach the units to the inputs:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-1 control-label">Height:</label>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">In</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">Weight:</label>
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">Lbs</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">BMI:</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
  </div>
  <label for="BI16" class="col-md-1 control-label">Waist:</label>
  <div class="col-md-2">
      <input type="text" id="BI16" name="medicareNumber" class="form-control" ng-model="hraFormData.HraValuesJson.BI16" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if you don't want this styling, but want it how the OP showed?

Comment: By "styling" do you mean the specific HTML? Bootstrap is quite specific with its CSS selectors, so you don't have an option to change the structure of your HTML. You need to match what they show in their documentation.

Comment: No, HTML doesn't (or shouldn't!) define styles. I'm referring to how Bootstrap renders addons, the sort of attached "box" with border and background. YMMV but that's not what the OP wanted. Reason I ask is because I wanted it too (gave up and shoved a `display:inline` on the input in the end).

Comment: The OP said they wanted to "set the "In" and"Lbs" right after their corresponding textbox". I understood the screenshot was what they currently had but not what they ultimately wanted. If you have a related but different question, post a link to it and I will take a look.

Comment: Sorry, it's not a related but different question, it's the same question. OP posted a screenshot and wanted to move the text, that's it. Your answer works but I was wondering whether there was something closer to what the OP asked for. Doesn't matter now

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I'm confused. The "In" and "Lbs" are now placed after their corresponding text boxes. That's what the OP wanted. What is incorrect?

Comment: The bootstrap way results in a little box with a background and border that is visually "attached" to the input. The OP and I have text characters, period. The styling is different. Sorry, I don't know how to say this any more clearly.

Comment: "The OP and I have text characters, period. The styling is different." Aha! I did not understand that part, I see. Bootstrap Input Groups do not offer variations. You can add an additional class to your addons and set the background color to `"transparent"` and remove the border.